# search value and count number from log file

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, unix

I've value in the logfile as below and I want to catch all the same number and count them and put in another file every 10 minutes. How can we do that ?

```
[14/06/2015 14:33:55.311] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=67 id2=69 number=1193046
[14/06/2015 14:33:55.607] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=70 id2=69 number=1193046
[14/06/2015 14:33:55.886] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=69 id2=70 number=466000000
[14/06/2015 14:33:56.086] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=64 id2=69 number=1193046
[14/06/2015 14:33:57.064] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=70 id2=69 number=1193046
[14/06/2015 14:33:57.074] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=64 id2=69 number=1193046
[14/06/2015 14:33:57.454] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=68 id2=70 number=466000000
[14/06/2015 14:33:57.657] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=68 id2=70 number=466000000
[14/06/2015 14:33:57.657] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=68 id2=70 number=466000000
[14/06/2015 14:33:58.309] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=67 id2=70 number=466000000
[14/06/2015 14:33:58.610] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=70 id2=69 number=1193046
[14/06/2015 14:33:58.814] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=68 id2=69 number=1193046
[14/06/2015 14:33:58.874] - WARNING- Conflict detected between two  sources !!! id1=69 id2=70 number=466000000
```

Comment: On another note, if the code which logs this data - if you own the code, try to print the timestamps in `YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:SS.ms` format (decreasing order of time unit). That becomes easy for sorting & simple string comparison. Currently, if you want to select data from only last 10 mins, you have to do some complex string manipulation & arithmetic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
cat log | grep -o "number\=[0-9]\+" | cut -d= -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```

The output for your example is:

```
7 1193046
6 466000000
```

Comment: Great, and how to collect every 10 minutes as I only want to collect number which logged newly in log file last 10 minutes.

Comment: This entire pipeline can be reduced to a single `awk`.

Comment: @anishsane: sure it is, but it is also normally way more difficult to read.

Comment: 1. ^^ I don't agree with this. For the new person, you need to know the meanings of different options for all the commands. 2. Plus, Having `sort | uniq -c` is generally avoided, because that unnecessarily consumes more memory, when you only want the count. Memory may not be a constraint today on a desktop system, but linux does get used on embedded systems as well. So having a unified script is generally a good idea. 3. `cat | grep` is [`uuoc`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html). Similar case with `grep | cut` & `sort | uniq -c`. Having less number of processes is advisable...

Comment: & I'm not saying that your answer is wrong. It's just inefficient. BTW, I didn't down vote your answer; I don't downvote answers unless they are 'wrong'... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the output of `Data::Dump` is sufficiently well-formatted for this, this is a trivial problem for Perl

```
perl -MData::Dump -e"/number=(\d+)/ and ++$c{$1} while <>; dd \%c;"  logfile.log
```

**output**

```
{ 1193046 => 7, 466000000 => 6 }
```

If (for whatever reason) you can't have `Data::Dump` installed then the output is slighlty less neat with the core module `Data::Dumper`

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e"/number=(\d+)/ and ++$c{$1} while <>; print Dumper \%c;"  logfile.log
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1193046' => 7,
          '466000000' => 6
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

awk one-liner in a while loop:

```
while true; do 
    awk '{a[$NF]++}END{for(t in a){printf "%d\t%s\n", a[t], gensub(/number=/,"",1,t)}}' logfile
    sleep 600
done
```

Output:

```
6       466000000
7       1193046
```

Comment: I would not normally answer this question, because OP shows no efforts of solving the question. Answering because the accepted answer (kind of) suggests inefficient method. I will add explanation to the answer, after OP posts some code he has tried.

Comment: I tried what enrico has suggested and found the output as I expected and that's why I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This perl script will print out your number and count for that number in a new file ('outfile.`file number`.txt') every 10 minutes

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my %hash;
my $count;
while (1) {
    open my $in, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;
    $count++;
        while(<$in>){
            chomp;
            my ($number) = /number=(\d+)/;
            $hash{$number}++;
        }
    open my $out, '>', "outfile.$count.txt" or die $!;
    print $out "$_\t$hash{$_}\n" foreach keys %hash;
    sleep 600;
}
```